# Change button background in Android when two activities

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I've searched a lot for a way to do this but no luck.

I have two Activities, Activity1 have 2 Buttons, Activity2 have 1 button, I would like that when I click on the Button in Activity2 makes the first button in Activity1 change its background.

Is it possible ?

Thanks a lot.

Here is Activity1

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private Vibrator myVib;
Intent receive = null;
String bg_color;
String text_color;
Button Q1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    myVib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    receive = getIntent();
    bg_color = receive.getStringExtra("bg_color");
     Q1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button Q2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


    Q1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Q01.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            myIntent.putExtra("bg_color", "#333333");
            myIntent.putExtra("text_color", "#cccccc");
            myVib.vibrate(50);
        }
    });

    Q2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Q02.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            myVib.vibrate(50);
        }
    });


}

public void receiveColor() {

    if (bg_color != null && text_color != null) {
        q1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(bg_color));

    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    receiveColor();

}

}
```

and here is my Q01 Activity ( second)

```
public class Q01 extends ActionBarActivity {
private Vibrator myVib;
Button ok;
Intent receiveColorIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myVib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    TextView type = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type);
    TextView type1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type1);
    TextView type2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type2);
    TextView type3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type3);
    final Button value = (Button) findViewById(R.id.value);
    TextView value1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value1);
    TextView value2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value2);
    TextView value3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value3);
    ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);

    type.setText(R.string.type01_);
    type1.setText(R.string.type01_1);
    type2.setText(R.string.type01_2);
    type3.setText(R.string.type01_3);
    value.setText(R.string.value01_);
    value1.setText(R.string.value01_1);
    value2.setText(R.string.value01_2);
    value3.setText(R.string.value01_3);




    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Q01.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("bg_color", "#FFF");
            i.putExtra("text_color", "#ccc");
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}

public void ReceiveColor() {

    receiveColorIntent = getIntent();
    if (receiveColorIntent != null) {
        String bg_color = receiveColorIntent.getStringExtra("bg_color");

        ok.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(bg_color));

    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    ReceiveColor();

}
```

}

Here the catlog `06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506): Process: com.example.quiz, PID: 9506
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.quiz/com.example.quiz.q01}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:209)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at com.example.cahllenge.Day01.ReceiveColor(q01.java:80)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at com.example.cahllenge.Day01.onResume(q01.java:90)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
06-10 23:45:21.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)`

Comment: But you wont see it happen.. And it is not possible to do that unless you start the activity with intent extras

Comment: So unless you want to see the activity1 on click of a button on activity2, just click on the button on activity 2 and use intent and pass the extra as a integer(some hex code for color) and on the activity one, onResume(), get the intent and the result of the previously created intent from activity2 and set the button background then. 

So basically initially when the app starts, nothing will happen to your button but on click of the button from other activity, your button bg will change.

Comment: What if I replace the button in Activity2 with a Checkbox?

Comment: If it's a checkbox, obviously you don't want to go the previous activity to check if the color was changed. But if you want to, start the activity when the checkbox is checked and pass the value you want to.

Comment: I dont want to start the activity.
What I want to do is, when the user finishes a quiz and clicks OK, in the main activity it shows that the user completed Quiz A and so on..

Comment: Save the data as a preference, this way the next time you open the application (let's say a day or a week from now), it will remember that Quiz A was completed. And every time you open an Activity, the Activity checks the preference to see what to show. And if there is no preference saved yet (therefore no Quiz completed yet), just make sure that the activity shows some predetermined default values of your choice.

Comment: There is something wrong with your error log: {com.example.quiz/com.example.quiz.q01} should be {com.example.quiz/com.example.quiz.Q01} with 'Q' capitalized. Most likely, you forgot to capitalize that class name in your Activity.

Comment: Please show us your Manifest and your Q02 activity as well

Comment: Manifest Is good. all the activities are declared.
Q02 is the same as Q01.

Comment: The button Q1 is first capitalized (as it should), then it's not.

Comment: Just change it and it isnt the problem.

Comment: Also, ReceiveColor() shouldn't start with a capital letter. I know, this is Mike's mistake, not yours. He mixed up his capitalizations. Please also change all your buttons instances to lower cases. q1 instead of Q1 and q2 instead of Q2. If you can't show your manifest, please tell me what capitalization you used for the activities in your manifest.

Comment: even if i pu receiveColor() it does not work..

Comment: It works now! But the when i leave the app, the default color comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Sample.

```
static int color=1;
 btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class); 
                i.putExtra("color", color);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

then in second

```
int color2;
color2= intent.getIntExtra("color", color2);

 if(color2==1);
// change button color
```

Answer (score 0):

**From your FirstActivity:**

**On Click of a button:**

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("bg_color", "#333333");
                i.putExtra("text_color", "#cccccc");
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

**On The Second Activity:**

```
public void ReceiveColor(){

        receiveColorIntent = getIntent();
        if(receiveColorIntent!=null){
        String bg_color = receiveColorIntent.getStringExtra("bg_color");
        String text_color = receiveColorIntent.getStringExtra("text_color");
        btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(bg_color));
        btn1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(text_color));
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        ReceiveColor();

    }
```

**Or**

Here's the complete Code for it:

**1)** Your Main Activity where you will be going to Second Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Intent receive = null;
    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    String bg_color;
    String text_color;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        receive = getIntent();
        bg_color = receive.getStringExtra("bg_color");
        text_color = receive.getStringExtra("text_color");

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("bg_color", "#333333");
                i.putExtra("text_color", "#cccccc");
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }

    public void receiveColor() {

        if (bg_color != null && text_color != null) {
            btn2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(bg_color));
            btn2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#cccccc"));
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        receiveColor();

    }

}
```

And 
**2)** From your Second Activity():

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn1;
    Intent receiveColorIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondlayout);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sbutton1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("bg_color", "#333333");
                i.putExtra("text_color", "#ccc");
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }

    public void ReceiveColor() {

        receiveColorIntent = getIntent();
        if (receiveColorIntent != null) {
            String bg_color = receiveColorIntent.getStringExtra("bg_color");
            String text_color = receiveColorIntent.getStringExtra("text_color");
            btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(bg_color));
            btn1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(text_color));
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        ReceiveColor();

    }

}
```

I am pretty sure this is one solution and it works great for me. You can try this and see it this works for you.

At least you can do this for now. And there are definitely other solutions too. But this works for me..:)

Comment: I get errors on the Second Activity.
receiveColorIntent cannot be resolved to a variable and so..

Comment: I edited my post and I have uploaded the complete code for it. It should definitely work my friend. I tried more than 10 times now. It works every time.. :)

Comment: i've upadted the question with a logcat.

Comment: Is it still not working ? Can you post your code snippet too ?